# AWS Cloudformation defining security policy of Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I'm struggling to find a security policy tab in cloudformation documentation for cloudfront.
Is there any way I can set the security policy to TLS1.1_2016? Because the default value is TLSv1.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The supported HTTP Version is in:

```
ViewerCertificate:
   MinimumProtocolVersion: TLSv1.1_2016
```

Comment: In case anyone's looking for it here's the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-viewercertificate.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-viewercertificate-minimumprotocolversion).

Answer (score 0):

The configuration that you are looking for is:

`HttpVersion: http2
 DefaultRootObject: index.html
 ViewerCertificate:
   SslSupportMethod: sni-only
   MinimumProtocolVersion: TLSv1.1_2016`